# Is there a way to auto-upload images to gitlab user profile?

Tags: gitlab

I have setup a gitlab instance recently. I am in the process of bulk creation of user accounts. I am trying to do that with the help of API. However, I don't see any option to upload images in user profiles. I don't want my users to manually upload the photos. Is there a way to automate that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no such possibility.